# Stop overriding from previous CSS properties

Tags: html, css

For example, given these two rules

```
p { color: red; background: yellow }
p { color: green }
```

paragraphs would appear in green text. They would also have a yellow background however, because the first rule is not completely negated. Its value for the color property is overridden by the second rule but its background-color is not in conflict, so it still applies.

So Is there anyway to stop applying background color property?

I am requiring such method because first rule may have n no. of attributes which i don't know beforehand. 
looking forward for positive reply.

Answer (score 0):

That's why you can define classes in CSS.

The style defined for the same element will be always overwritten if there are duplicated properties and inherited from the previous definition for the same element.

Try:

CSS

```
p.red { color: red; background: yellow }
p.green { color: green }
```

HTML

```
<p class="green">Some text</p>
<p class="red">Another text</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for very fast reply... But in my case I insert some HTML tags on website at run time but because of already present content on third party website like p { color: red; background: yellow } affects my component's display. hence creating problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Define a class to each <p> element. Set CSS style for each defined class.

HTML File (index file)

```
<p class="content-1">This is content 1</p>
<p class="content-2">This is content 2</p>
```

CSS file (style.css)

```
p.content-1 {
    color: red; background: yellow;
}
p.content-2 {
    color: green;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SCLP8/

Comment: Thanks for very fast reply... But in my case I insert some HTML tags on website at run time but because of already present content on third party website like p { color: red; background: yellow } affects my component's display. hence creating problem for me.

Comment: In such a case, you can use parent selector in order to distinguish different <p>.

For example `.main p {} ` and `.footer p {} `

Answer (score 0):

You can add the background property to your own CSS like this:

```
p { color: red; background: yellow; }
p { color: green; background: none; }
```

There won't be a yellow background.

Comment: Yes You are right but in case I don't know which are all properties present on third party website. Hence unable to decide which property should have default value. Also List of properties are huge.Then in that case I have to give values to every other property/properties. Thanks for reply